# Filter empty nodes on GitHub GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, github-api

I'm trying to use the V4 API of GITHUB to get a list of my assigned issues along with its labels and references.

After some time I got the query you can see below, which works exactly how I want.

There is however, a problem: it includes a lot of empty nodes I am not interested at. For example, if I want to get all the CrossReferencedEvent that are issues I will get a lot of empty nodes on the timeline edges array because the other events: LabeledEvent, ReferencedEvent, AssignedEvent etc.

How can I filter out those so I only get the events I am interested at?
Is this a limitation of graphql? Am I forced to remove the useless nodes locally?
This is the query that I have currently

```
{
  search(query: "assignee:danielo515", type: ISSUE, last: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Issue {
          number
          title
          state
          timeline(first: 10) {
            edges {
              node {
                ... on CrossReferencedEvent {
                   source{
                    ... on Issue {
                      title
                      number
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          labels(last: 10) {
            nodes {
              name
              color
            }
          }
          repository {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

One improvement I can make is, on the query part add `is:issue`. This will . save me all the empty nodes at the root edges array, but I don't see how to do the same for the nested timeline.

Thanks in advance